# NTP on a Google Cloud Debian 10 VM (Time goes out of sync)

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, gcloud, ntp, chrony

In one of my Debian VM (**Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)**), I see that the time sync service has some issues. The **machine clock falls behind the standard time by a couple of minutes every now & then.** The **local timezone** of the machine is set to **IST**.

I need to restart the service with the following command (**sudo service chrony restart**) to get the time synced again.

**Any solution for this?**

Thr gcloud docs link for this is given below:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/configure-ntp

**Logs:** I do not see any errors in the logs (most likely it was wiped out), but after restarting the log looks like this (**you can see the adjustments made**):

```
Starting chrony, an NTP client/server... 
chronyd version 3.4 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS
+SECHASH +IPV6 -DEBUG) 
Frequency -93.458 +/- 0.001 ppm read from /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift 
Loaded seccomp filter 
Started chrony, an NTP client/server. 
Selected source 169.254.169.254 System clock wrong by 98.886791 seconds, adjustment started 
System clock was stepped by 98.886791 seconds
```

I am using the **default config file** (/etc/chrony/chrony.conf):

```
server metadata.google.internal prefer iburst
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys
logdir /var/log/chrony
maxupdateskew 100.0
rtcsync
makestep 1 3
```

Comment: Hello, I’ve tried to reproduce your issue but I’ve been unable to do so, and as there’s no way to troubleshoot this, I would like to recommend you to open a [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures).

Comment: Thank you @Pit , it is a bit weird. Because my VM is always online, it was never suspended or restarted when this issue occurred. I am trying a few options mentioned to me on gcloud community, will update on the findings.